# Color the background based on value

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have collected multiple time series for evaluation and further use in MATLAB.
I am aware there are ways to change the color of a plot based on its value.
But in my case I would like to change the background color of a plot based on one data series and have other plots in front.

Maybe the words don't explain it too well, so I tried to make a clear example:

[image]

In this plot, the background was colored according to data series 1, in the foreground data series 2 is plotted as a line plot in blue.

Is there a way to achieve this using MATLAB?

Comment: What I'd do is create an `imagesc` plot with colours as desired to your matrix, then plot that and then with `hold on` add the data series over it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. That's indeed a nice way!